# Compute Kernel Density from Scratch

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a continuous variable in list form. From this I want to create a new list that contains the data to plot its smoothed distribution (kernel density).

Most tutorials use the kernel functions that are built-in to the statistics package, so it's almost like a black box. I actually want a more organic approach to get those values for export to csv/json. I'm using native Python, but numpy may also work.

This is what I have:

```
my_variable
>> [51.43, 52.04, 52.28, ... 164.25]
```

[image]

My desired output is a list containing values of Epanechnikov kernel density plot:

```
my_density_values_x
>> [0,10,20,30...240]

my_density_values_y
>> [0,0,.02,.02,.04...]
```

[image]

So my question is, is generating the distribution x and y series feasible in native Python? It seems so simple, but I can't figure out how to get my desired kernel distribution values.

Comment: To make this a bit simpler, can you give the example inputs with the desired outputs.

Comment: @ColinSchoen I also found the post slightly unclear after re-visiting it. I rephrased things and added more content.